# Pantheon DE doesn't show up

Tags: 18.04, lts, pantheon

I've installed pantheon DE but it doesn't show up when I reboot.
I've installed it on my machine which running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I've followed this tutorial when installing pantheon DE:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pantheon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux-desktop

Comment: Did you select it as your desktop at login?   I didn't read the post, but usually they add the desktop as a second desktop meaning you can use your old one (which I assume was gnome) or Pantheon - you select it when you login (if you autologin you'll be missing the step, so logout and you can then choose).  How you choose depends on your used display manager.

Comment: There is several DE options but none of it is pantheon